# Music app crash

Tags: music, crash

I have a little problem with the music app. When I try to play a .FLAC file, the application starts and shows a message (Analyzing Changes). Many seconds after, the application closes automatically.

I have elementary 0.4 Freya with the last updates. Does anybody have any idea about this issue?

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: Awesome, i unmount the ftp server and now work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I found the workaround here:
https://github.com/elementary/music/issues/391

It crashes on startup if an NTFS partition is mounted.

I unmounted all network shares and it doesn't crash on startup for me anymore.